# Elasticsearch does not log kibana due to filebeat

Tags: .net, docker, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch for logging. I did a little research and implemented some code in the application, which was developed with .NET 7. All services run almost without any problems. However, I can't see the logs in Kibana. I see the following warning in the log section: `Set up Filebeat (opens in a new tab or window), then configure your Elasticsearch output for your monitoring cluster.`

My docker-compose files:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
   backend:
   fronted:

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

include:
   - "external-services.yml"
   - "internal-services.yml"
```

Part of external-services.yml:

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.1
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false 
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled=true
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - backend

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.9.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.9.1
    user: root
    environment:
      - output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - esdata:/var/log/app/
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same problem.
After upgrading Beats to version 8.9.x, our ELK stack no longer receives logs. We are using version 2.9.0 for everything except Filebeat. You might want to consider downgrading Beats to version 8.8.x; it has worked for us temporarily."